# Will there be hats on Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, fun, winter-bash-2014

They were on Meta Stack Overflow previous year, but since the split occurred, I would expect them to appear here, on Meta Stack Exchange, this year. Will it happen (or any discussion on it)? I want hatz!

Comment: you are aware that users asking questions too early about those winter-wearables are excluded from participating?

Comment: @rene :( But it doesn't seem to be early. Look at your calendar, Nov 22 already!

Comment: btw didn't you see it http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277407/do-we-want-hats/277436#277436

Comment: @TMG Sure I did. It has my upvote :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes!!! of course I want hat.

[image]

<sub>[Source : Meta Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277407/do-we-want-hats/277436#277436)</sub>

Comment: You'd better highlight "Oui" a bit ;)

Comment: This question is about hats, not about cats :D

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion hehe doesn't matter on meta..!!

Comment: a cat in a hat, on a mat - and that is that...

Comment: Please provide a hat for this [cute cat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244101/245167)

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion yeah sure :)

Answer (score 22):

[Hats](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com), meow.

[image]

Comment: <3 Thats cute :)

Answer (score 16):

Please let there be hats! I want hats!

Comment: You deserve a police hat @Uni :D

Comment: [status-needz-a-hat]. Why does your answer lack a hat?!?!

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Yes you're right.. can someone give police hat to him :D

Comment: I accept your answer as a first agreement with my discussion.

Answer (score 16):

Please give us hats on MSE, so that we can wear our hats while chatting in the Tavern and other MSE chatrooms.

Hats are fun, please give us hats.

[image]

([bluefeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164200/bluefeet) in a red hat^)

[image]

Comment: Red hats are better @bluefeet :D

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion very bad choice :P see below cat gif she has a black hat & looking good ! :)

Comment: Red is the perfect color for the winter holidays @TGMCians.

Answer (score 16):

I can neither condemn nor deny the potential existence of hats.

[HATS!](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=1713209#1713209)

[image: screenshot of my profile, wearing a hat]

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Answer (score 9):

A moderator on SO asked the community of SO if we wanted hats again this year [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277407/do-we-want-hats).

According to the overwhelming support of the community wanting hats again this year, it is safe to say, in my opinion, that there will be hats again. I'd think the hats will be network wide, including MSE.

<sub>Please be warned that Winterbash has been accused of causing finger pain, insomnia, hallucinations, and anti-social behaviors. Please consult with your doctor before participating. If you feel rage, followed by extreme emotions of bliss, please seek help right away. 9 out of 10 Winterbash participants say that their life or work has been set back 6-8 months after participating for the full length of the Winterbash. Participating in Winterbash is at your own risk and under no circumstances will you find every secret hat.</sub>

Comment: But I am talking about MSE, not SO... Seems that every site has its own discussion.

Comment: @nicael IIRC when MSO was a separate site, it has separate hats, so it stands to reason that it will be part of the re-branded MSE.

Comment: Hats won't be entirely network-wide if some sites opt-out.

Comment: Much better now. Thanks for warning me :)

Comment: The conversation on Meta Stack Overflow has nothing to do with any other sites on the network. Stack Exchange asks the moderators of each site whether they want their site to participate in the event, and the easiest way is to just ask the community.

Answer (score 5):

Don't hate hats. WEAR THEM ON YOUR HEAD. (Or on your feet. There are few rules on the internet, you know.)

Answer (score 4):

**HAT**S!  t**hat** is a good plan t**hat** is being **hat**ched!

Comment: Ah yes, I knew I missed one @nicael

Comment: LOL I think that bad pun here earned me a downvote - it was worth it!

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is wrong and goes against everything that MSE stands for … but, speaking entirely selfishly, I'd like the same hat acquisitions to take effect on SO, MSO and MSE. Since the split, frankly, I still see MSO as basically the same as MSE (yeah, yeah, I know) and my "workflow" (such as it is) follows suit. Thus it would be jarring to find myself having different hats on MSE than on [M]SO.

I basically just had to say it. I feel better now.

Comment: I have to agree.

Answer (score 2):

[image]