# What is a "hat"?

Tags: support, winter-bash

What exactly is a hat?

I have seen a lot of people arguing the significance of hats and the limited edition hats. I know the hats are sort of linked to the Winterbash stuff, but what **exactly** is a hat, what does it do, how do I get one?

Is there a full list of hats?

Comment: Hat gives you magical powers and you also get to chat with [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227588/244282) unicorn if you win at-least one [secret hat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211707/244282).

Comment: ...I don't understand. At all. What are you trying to say -- chat with the unicorn and give you magical powers? Can you clear up a bit, if that is a serious comment? XD

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will there be hats on Meta Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244009/will-there-be-hats-on-meta-stack-exchange)

Comment: Yeah, I know, I'm a spoiler....  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat

Comment: I just deleted my own comment... (Original: You sure it's a duplicate? How does it relate?)

Comment: @rene I don't think it's a dupe. Looks like the OP here is not familiar with the concept itself, which is exlained nicely in the blog: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/

Comment: Also see the [FAQ for last year's event](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: @ShadowWizard that is true...still not going to retract my vote...

Comment: @rene I take it that your goal is to get icecream? ;-)

Comment: Yes, please serve in the Tavern @ShadowWizard

Comment: @rene [status-completed](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2696262#2696262) ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because I can't even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hats are the main focus of the online Team Fortress 2 (the shooting aspect is a side-effect). Their popularity has flooded over to Stack Exchange, and over the winter period you can earn hats by getting 10 upvotes on a question to much harder tasks and therefore rarer hats.

Once you unlock a hat, you can wear it on your gravatar.

See [last years list](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/) for hats and their requirements.

Comment: Do I wear this permanently if I collected it? Also, are 2014 hats the same as 2013 hats?

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 not permanently, only during Winterbash event which is about three weeks. Hats are going to be different.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Thank you. So I can start collecting the hats when the Winterbash 2014 event starts.

Comment: True @Arc, and also worth to mention it all started on the gaming site three years ago: http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/ and when the team saw how successful it was, they made it network wide last year. :)

Answer (score 5):

Hats are invented to bring fun!
Hats are loved by everyone!
Hats  - main subject of meta disputes
(maybe *debates* there will better suit).

If you hate hats, aware of cats<sup>1</sup>,
They can hunt you down and bite you to death!
Await for another fate if you love them,
A unicorn will bring you some tasty jam :)

The hats are everywhere!..
Just keep your eyes open
And you'll find *anywhere*
A ton of hatzzzz.

But please be aware that they disappear
And *maybe* it'll make you despair...
However nothing's bad, drink a glass of beer -
They'll reappear next year.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> - somewhere there was a meme displaying a kitten and and words like this: "I will hunt you down... and eat you"; didn't you see it?

Also, please don't bite me, english isn't my mother tongue :)</sup>