# winterbash2014.stackexchange.com is broken (When does Winter Bash 2014 start and end?)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2013, subdomains, winter-bash-2014

When I open [winterbash2014.stackexchange.com](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) I get

> The Q&A site winterbash2014.stackexchange.com doesn't seem to exist…*yet*.

This is the same message as when I visit [unicorns.stackexchange.com](http://unicorns.stackexchange.com/):

> The Q&A site unicorns.stackexchange.com doesn't seem to exist…*yet*.

When I open [winterbash2013.stackexchange.com](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/), I see a wonderful message about hats, among other things:

> Stack Exchange invites you to celebrate the end of a great year …with *HATS!*

Please start Winter Bash 2014! :D (And let us know how long we will have to earn hats)

Comment: I would consider non-existence of unicorns.se to be more serious bug. And winterbash2014.se really doesn't exist... yet. Sure it will be :)

Comment: Is this a request to start Winterbash 2014... ? It's already planned to start at some point in the near future, I presume. It just hasn't yet. I don't think a request is needed to remind SE to start the event they planned, though.

Comment: @JasonC Maybe not, but we're allowed to have fun on meta, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Mooseman The hat-related free-rep thread is already here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244009/will-there-be-hats-on-meta-stack-exchange/ I don't think we really need any more.

Comment: @Jas What?! You hate fun???!!!

Comment: @nicael http://westchestertownhall.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Straw-Man_500.gif

Comment: [meta-tag:status-deferred]?

Comment: Guys, really -9? It doesn't deserve this score.

Comment: @nicael Is that any better now :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

WinterBash 2014 is scheduled to begin December 15th. It's been [posted](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/should-we-sign-up-for-winter-bash-2014) by [moderators](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191/does-moderators-se-want-to-participate-in-winter-bash-2014?cb=1) of various [exchanges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277407/do-we-want-hats) to see which sites are and are not interested in participating.

The event will run from 15 December 2014 to 4 January 2015.

Comment: What about unicorns.se?

Comment: unicorns.se is a super secret site that you aren't privileged to. Only verified owners of a unicorn get to see that page. Sorry. Get yourself a unicorn. ;)

Comment: Just putting my seal of authenticity on this answer. The site won't be up until Winter Bash 2014 actually begins.

Comment: @Laura well, it is up now with a cool countdown. Was it a last minute decision? (adding a countdown)

Comment: Next year can we make sure we don't make those in the southern hemisphere feel left out?

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah, that was a spontaneous decision by balpha. :)

Comment: @paulmorriss have any specific ideas for how we can do better?

Comment: Heck of a good job for a spontaneous decision then, @Laura! He surely deserves a special hat for that. :D

Comment: @laura End of Year bash (eoybash)?

Answer (score 5):

There is something interesting on http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/enter, CHECK IT NOW! ;) at least it is not broken anymore! :)

---

## YAY HATZ!

http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com works now! We have hatz!!! (<s>But I have no appropriate avatar to wear them :(</s> What the hell did I *just* say?! )

Comment: Nyan cat :o :o :o

Comment: I'm glad my first guess of 'unicorns' was correct for the password so I could see the nyan cat :P

Answer (score 3):

Not broken anymore!

[image]

Enjoy the cool countdown! :)

Comment: I got a different number on mine :/

Comment: @PeterJ lol! :D